# How to get result from LaunchUriAsync(Uri)

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store

I'm use the following function to prompt the user to rate my app:

```
Launcher.LauLauncher.LaunchUriAsync(
    new Uri("ms-windows-store:reviewapp?appid=" + APP_ID))
```

I want to check if user click on the "Cancel" button in page rating.

How can I check if the user clicks on the "Cancel" button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you're asking whether it's possible to determine whether the user actually left a rating/review when you invoke the Store URI. Unfortunately, this isn't possible at present, but it is a frequently requested capability.